# Print results of a loop in a dataframe

Tags: loops, lm, anova

I wrote a code that splits a dataframe `data` according to a factor a and for each level of the factor returns an anova table for the factor b.

```
for (i in 1:length(levels(data$a))){
  levels<-levels(data$a)
  assign(paste("data_", levels[i], sep = ""), subset(data, a==levels[i]))
  print (levels[i])
  print(anova(lm(var~b, subset(data, a==levels[i]))))
}
```

The result is exactly what I want, but I would like to have all the anova tables pooled and returned as a unique list or data frame.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this code does the trick:

```
result_anova<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(levels(data$a))){
  levels<-levels(data$a)
  assign(paste("data_", levels[i], sep = ""), subset(data, a==levels[i]))
  result<-as.data.frame(anova(lm(var~b, subset(data, a==levels[i]))))
  result_anova[i, 1]<-levels[i]
  result_anova[i, 2]<-result[1, 1 ]
  result_anova[i, 3]<-result[1, 2 ]
  result_anova[i, 4]<-result[1, 3 ]
  result_anova[i, 5]<-result[1, 4 ]
  result_anova[i, 6]<-result[1, 5 ]
  result_anova[i, 7]<-result[2, 1 ]
  result_anova[i, 8]<-result[2, 2 ]
  result_anova[i, 9]<-result[2, 3 ]
  result_anova[i, 10]<-result[2, 4 ]
  result_anova[i, 11]<-result[2, 5 ]
  colnames(result_anova_genos)<-c ( "genotype", "Df_fac", "Sum_Sq_fac",  "Mean_Sq_fac", "F_value_fac", "Pr(>F)_fac", "Df_res", "Sum_Sq_res",  "Mean_Sq_res", "F_value_res", "Pr(>F)_res")
}
```

Please vote this answer or let me know if this code can be improved.